# Pass arguments in shell securely

Tags: python, linux, shell, security, command-line

How safe it is to pass sensitive information to script from command line as an arguments? For example, I have a Python script and I am going to pass username and password as arguments.

```sh
python collect.py --username <username> --password <password>
```

Is above example safe? What's the best design patterns, when working on sensitive command line arguments?

Answer (score 3):

You may use `getpass()` from the `getpass` module:

```
from getpass import getpass

password = getpass("Password: ")
```

This will prompt for an input, but when you type something, it will not show up in the command line. This is good, because your input will not be visible in the command history. To answer your question, the downside of your solution is that the whole command will be visible in the command history.

Note that using `getpass()`, your program will prompt for the password **after** you started it, instead of you passing it at the start as an argument next to `--password`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I know about this module. I do not want prompt, this is problem.

Comment: Then you may pass a file path to your `--password` switch, which contains your password, if you are worried about it staying in the history. Later, you can delete the file. Although, using this method, you wouldn't need the switch at all.